# How to declare a variable in a PostgreSQL query when the variable need to exists in an array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, variables, declare

How to declare a variable in a PostgreSQL query when the variable need to exists in an array,
meaning my column is an array and I want to check if either one of my variable exists in that array.

My query:

```
DO $$
    DECLARE thetag1 text = 'tag1';
        thetag2 text = 'tag2';
BEGIN 
    CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
    p.id
FROM table_1 p
WHERE (thetag1 = ANY (p.tags::text[]))
      AND 
      (thetag2 = ANY (p.tags::text[]));
END $$;
SELECT * FROM tmp_table;
```

- the column p.tags is charcater varying [] (255).
- I got the messages: The specified object could not be found.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Please include a CREATE statement for creating table_1 which causes this error to occur.

Comment: "The specified object could not be found" does not look like wording PostgreSQL would use for an error message.  Is it being generated by your client code?